# PASAR A FORMATO PDF Y ENVIAR EL CORREO CON PHPMAILER

Tags: php

Tengo el contenido html almacenado en una variable php pero quiero pasarlo al formato pdf para poder enviar el correo y no tengo idea como hacerlo, ayuda por favor

```php
$contenido = '
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
          <tr><th  colspan="6" style="text-align: center;">Ficha Técnica de Evaluación y Descripción de Actividades</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Usuario:</b></td><td>'.$o['cod_local'].'</td>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Giro del Lugar:</b></td><td>'.$cadena_giro.'</td>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Fecha:</b></td><td>'.substr($o['fecha_creacion'], 0, 10).'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Dirección:</b></td><td colspan="3">'.$o['direccion'].'</td>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Inicio:</b></td><td>'.substr($o['fechahora_inicio'], 11).'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Condición Sanitaria Circundante:</b></td><td colspan="3">'.$o['condicion_sanitaria'].'</td>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Final:</b></td><td>'.substr($o['fechahora_fin'], 11).'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Servicio:</b></td><td colspan="6">'.$o['servicio'].'</td>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><b>Ambientes tratados:</b></td>
          <td colspan="5">'.$cadena_ambientes.'</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
';
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar lo que has intentado o investigado. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para añadir detalles a tu pregunta. También puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.